# Load and draw png with Direct2D

Tags: c#, directx, direct2d, wic

I am getting started with using Direct2D with c#.

I've downloaded and used [this example app](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113991/Using-Direct-D-with-WPF).

The application works fine, but I also need it to load png images from the hard drive and display them.

In the sample, this would be done in the function `OnRender`, probably with `RenderTarget.DrawBitmap`.

However, I'm having a problem with actually loading png into memory. I understand I should use something like `WICImagingFactory` for it, but I can't find the class and I'm not sure how to use it to get the `D2DBitmap` object that is required by `RenderTarget.DrawBitmap`

Can anyone provide a c# example how to load image into Direct2D?

Comment: Have you looked at using [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D)?

Comment: yea, just finished playing with SharpDX

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with using SharpDX.

Here's a good example how to load image with SharpDX: https://english.r2d2rigo.es/2014/08/12/loading-and-drawing-bitmaps-with-direct2d-using-sharpdx/

```
ImagingFactory imagingFactory = new ImagingFactory();
NativeFileStream fileStream = new NativeFileStream(@"D:\path\myfile.png",
    NativeFileMode.Open, NativeFileAccess.Read);

BitmapDecoder bitmapDecoder = new BitmapDecoder(imagingFactory, fileStream, DecodeOptions.CacheOnDemand);
BitmapFrameDecode frame = bitmapDecoder.GetFrame(0);

FormatConverter converter = new FormatConverter(imagingFactory);
converter.Initialize(frame, SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPRGBA);

newBitmap = SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap1.FromWicBitmap(target, converter); 

target.DrawBitmap(newBitmap,new RawRectangleF(0,0,target.Size.Width,target.Size.Height),1,BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear );
```

Also, in case you want to do the whole program with SharpDX (so you don't end up using 2 different semi-incompatible frameworks), here's a working example how this can be done: https://github.com/dalance/D2dControl